# Inner join returning duplicate records access sql

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the below table. the only difference in data is **suff, wt**; the rest of them look the same.

Things table

```
  Prefix  Baseletter  suff   CSCcode   Description  WT      BNO      BNO-CSCcode 

  EIGC    A5560        BGA    04020    blah1        0       5560      5560-04020
  EIGC    A5560        HEA    04020    blah2        17.9    5560      5560-04020
```

Mapp table

```
  BNO      BNO-CSCcode    EID    Description   

  5560      5560-04020   4005    blah1
  5560      5560-04020   4011    blah2
```

I'm trying to inner join them using **BNO-CSCcode** to get EID for corresponding **BNO**. But my query is returning duplicates. I'm getting 4 records, even though the first table only has two records.

My SQL query:

```
SELECT 
  Things.Prefix ,
  Things.Baseletter,
  Things.suff,
  Things.CSCcode,
  Things.WT,
  Mapping.BNO-CSCcode,
  Mapping.EID 
FROM 
  Things 
  INNER JOIN Mapping ON Things.BNO-CSCcode = Mapping.BNO-CSCcode
```

Why am I getting these duplicates, and how can I fix that?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`BNO-CSCcode` contains duplicates.  You are joining the first record of `Things` to both records of `Mapp`, then the second record of `Things` joins to both records of `Mapp`.  Giving you a total of 4 records.

If you want to join these together, you need some unique way of identifying the rows between the tables.

A Distinct should bring it back down to 2 records, but likely you need to join on a few more fields to get it to 2 records:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  Things.Prefix,
  Things.Baseletter,
  Things.suff,
  Things.CSCcode,
  Things.WT,
  Mapping.BNO-CSCcode,
  Mapping.EID 
FROM 
  Things 
  INNER JOIN Mapping ON Things.BNO-CSCcode = Mapping.BNO-CSCcode
```

Comment: Result didn't change when using DISTINCT

Comment: @vuyy1182 What column is different between the rows?

Comment: It is **Suff** column

Comment: @vuyy1182 Then I think perhaps your data is not like your example.  Why would `suff` be different across tables?

Comment: In the present table only difference is suffix but in the real i have more than 800 records, might be any of them different **BNO** or **CSCode** is different in some rows.

Comment: @vuyy1182 order the query by `BNO-CSCcode` AND `suff`, find your duplicates and see what other columns are different.

Answer (score 4):

You are getting duplicates because both records in the `Things` table have a `BNO-CSCcode` of 5560-04020, as do both records in the `Mapp` table.  The only distinction between the two that I can see is the `Description` field.  So, if you use the following query:

```
SELECT Things.Prefix ,Things.Baseletter,Things.suff,Things.CSCcode,Things.WT,Mapping.BNO-CSCcode,Mapping.EID
FROM Things INNER JOIN Mapping ON Things.BNO-CSCcode = Mapping.BNO-CSCcode AND 
Things.Description = Mapping.Description
```

...you should eliminate the duplication.

However, using a field that is obviously a text field in a join is not best practice, as if they are separately user-generated, they are unlikely to match, and it takes longer (relatively speaking) to match fields with a higher byte-count than those with low byte-counts.

Comment: Not **Description** field is diffirent. **Suff** is different. But that doesn't exists in Mapping table.

Comment: What do you mean by "Not Description field is different"?  Do you mean to say that records in `Mapp` won't necessarily have the same `Description`s as in `Things`?

Answer (score 2):

```
    select
       A.Code,
       B.Code as CustomerBeneficiaryCode,
       C.AccountNo as  CustomerBeneficiaryBankAccountNo
       ,COUNT(*) as Duplicate

from Table A
inner join  Table B on A.id = B.CustomerIndividualId
inner join  Table C on B.Id = C.CustomerBeneficiaryId

group by C.AccountNo,B.Code,A.Code having COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
SELECT DISTINCT Prefix,
            Baseletter,
            suff,
            CSCcode,
            WT,
            BNO_CSCcode,
            EID
FROM (
       SELECT Things.Prefix AS Prefix,
              Things.Baseletter AS Baseletter,
              Things.suff AS suff,
              Things.CSCcode AS CSCcode,
              Things.WT AS WT,
              Mapping.BNO - CSCcode AS BNO_CSCcode,
              Mapping.EID AS EID
         FROM Things
              INNER JOIN
              Mapping ON Things.BNO - CSCcode = Mapping.BNO - CSCcode
   );
```